# regular expression: edit regexp for string

Tags: regex

I have a String

```
1) Compatible Model: Some ipads <br>2) Compatible Model: iPad 4 / New iPad (iPad 3) / iPad 2
```

I have a regexp `(>[0-9]{1,3}\)|^[0-9]{1,3}\))`

This regexp match `1)` and `>2)`. 
This regexp work is correctly but matched with `>` symbol. 
It is not needed

Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use lookbehind(`(?<=>)`) in your regex?

```
((?<=>)[0-9]{1,3}\)|^[0-9]{1,3}\))
```

This lookbehind is check whether the > character exists before the `[0-9]` or not. Otherwise it will ignore this.

Comment: what about strings like 1) Compatible Model: Some ipads <br>2) Compatible Model: iPad 4 / New iPad (iPad 3) / iPad 2 (5>4)

Comment: aelor, I hope that this line will not be

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this:

```
\d\)
```

This seems to be working. It captures a digit followed by a `)`